# flat list android animation doesn't work as expected

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-animatable

I am trying to make an animation on items that inside flatList.
Each item will appear from right to left.
On IOS It's work fine but on ANDROID not.

the animation contains fade in and transform: translateX animation.

If there another way to make like on IOS I will be glad to here, It's supposed to be a dynamic list

**FadeInView component:**

```
export class FadeInView extends Component {
state = {
    rightToLeftAnim: new Animated.Value(450),
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
};

componentDidMount() {
    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.delay((this.props.index + 1) * 1000),
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.rightToLeftAnim,
                {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad),
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }
            ),
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.fadeAnim,
                {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 1000,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }
            )
        ])
    ]).start();

}

render() {
    let { fadeAnim,rightToLeftAnim } = this.state;

    const rightToLeft = {
        transform: [{translateX: rightToLeftAnim}]
    };

    return (
        <Animated.View                
            style={[rightToLeft,{flex: 1, ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim,}]}
        >
            {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

}

**parent component:**

```
 class MyPlans extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }
    render() {
    return (
        <View>
                <FlatList
                    style={{marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 60}}
                    data={[{key: 'module a'},{key: 'module b'},{key: 'module c'},{key: 'module d'}]}
                    horizontal={true}
                    renderItem={({item,index}) => <FadeInView index={index} style={this.moduleStyle}><Text>{item.key}</Text></FadeInView>}
                />
        </View>);
}
```

[image: ANDROID][image: IPHONE]

Answer (score 0):

Give `style={{flex:1}}` to View Component, which the parent of FlatList.

```
return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                    style={{marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 60}}
                    data={[{key: 'module a'},{key: 'module b'},{key: 'module c'},{key: 'module d'}]}
                    horizontal={true}
                    renderItem={({item,index}) => <FadeInView index={index} style={this.moduleStyle}><Text>{item.key}</Text></FadeInView>}
                />
        </View>);
```

Answer (score -1):

please use flatList getItemLayou property,or updata rn version to 0.59.5 above.

Comment: This is not acceptable as an answer, please add a complete explanation of the method you're suggesting, or use a comment instead